# How to run php composer through plesk panel?

Tags: php, cron, composer-php, octobercms

I need to create October CMS project, instruction is here: https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation
But I have only hosting with Plesk panel.

I try use cron for this, but "composer" command not finded.
Can I use command "composer" in cron through Plesk? How?

Comment: Use the command line interface to [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/) first.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I had the error install: missing destination file operand after ‘composer’

Comment: Please share more details - why do you need Cron for this? Why not install all dependencies on a local server, and copy everything to your server?

Comment: @NicoHaase just for fun, Now I did it through command "php composer.phar install"